# multithreading problem in boost asio example

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, asio

I'm developing a tcp service, and I took an example from boost asio to start (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_server.cpp), and I'm worried about something, as I understand, any time you want to send something you have to use the **deliver** function that check the status of and run some operations over the **write_msgs_** queue (in my code **write_msgs_** is a queue of std::byte based structures):

```
  void deliver(const chat_message& msg)
  {
    bool write_in_progress = !write_msgs_.empty();
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    if (!write_in_progress)
    {
      do_write();
    }
  }
```

and inside the do_write() function you will see an asynchronous call wrapping a lambda function:

```
void do_write()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
          write_msgs_.front().length()),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            write_msgs_.pop_front();
            if (!write_msgs_.empty())
            {
              do_write();
            }
          }
          else
          {
            room_.leave(shared_from_this());
          }
        });
  }
```

where the call is constantly sending messages until the queue is empty.

Now, as I understand, the boost::asio::async_write make the lambda function thread safe, but, as the **write_msgs_** is open to be used in the **deliver** function which is out of the isolation given by the **io_context** a mutex is needed. Now, should I put a mutex each time the write_queue is used or is cheaper to use the **boost::asio::post()** calling the **deliver** function to isolate the **write_msgs_** from asynchronous calls ?

something like this:

```
boost::asio::io_service srvc; // this somewhere 
void deliver2(const chat_message &msg)
{
   srvc.post(std::bind(&chat_session::deliver,this,msg)); 
}
```

Comment: The example doesn't use threads do the code is safe, everything executes on the main thread

Comment: I forgot to mention I need this to be used over other threads, that's why my concern.

Comment: I don't think this example is a good starting point for a multithreaded app, it has many places that will cause issues